# Infinite gas warning in Remix for a function

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

Can anyone tell why the above warning is generated when putting this function into Remix?

```
 function doFlip() public{
       uint256 blockValue = uint256(blockhash(block.number - 1));
       uint256 coinFlip = uint256(uint256(blockValue)/FACTOR);
       side = coinFlip == 1 ? true : false;
       flipper.flip(side);
    }
```

The full contract looks like follows:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicensed
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-ethereum-package/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

interface CoinFlip {
    function flip(bool guess) external returns (bool);
 }
 
contract Flipper {

    using SafeMath for uint256;
    uint256 FACTOR = 57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968;
    bool public side;
    CoinFlip public flipper;
    
    constructor() public {
        flipper = CoinFlip(xxxxxxxxxx);
    }
    
 

   function doFlip() public{
       uint256 blockValue = uint256(blockhash(block.number - 1));
       uint256 coinFlip = uint256(uint256(blockValue)/FACTOR);
       side = coinFlip == 1 ? true : false;
       flipper.flip(side);
    }
    
   

}
```

The CoinFlip contract looks as follows:

```
/ SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol';

contract CoinFlip {

  using SafeMath for uint256;
  uint256 public consecutiveWins;
  uint256 lastHash;
  uint256 FACTOR = 57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968;

  constructor() public {
    consecutiveWins = 0;
  }

  function flip(bool _guess) public returns (bool) {
    uint256 blockValue = uint256(blockhash(block.number.sub(1)));

    if (lastHash == blockValue) {
      revert();
    }

    lastHash = blockValue;
    uint256 coinFlip = blockValue.div(FACTOR);
    bool side = coinFlip == 1 ? true : false;

    if (side == _guess) {
      consecutiveWins++;
      return true;
    } else {
      consecutiveWins = 0;
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the `CoinFlip` contract deployed on the address defined in the constructor? On the Remix local network or on some other network (e.g. Rinkeby, Ropsten, ...)?

Comment: Yes, indeed, deployed on the same network

Comment: In that case, can you update the question and share the `flip()` function body (as well as its dependencies such as contract properties that it accesses)? My guess is that the `flip()` function has a failing `require()` condition that throw an exception, and since the `doFlip()` doesn't catch the exception, it reverts the transaction - causing the infinite gas amount message. But it's just a guess without the code and values to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Added the CoinFlip contract that has the flip() function. As you can see, it doesn't have a require and looks quite basic

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's an ongoing problem with the Remix JavaScript emulator of the EVM, that fails to calculate the `blockhash()`.

I was able to reproduce the issue:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    function foo() external returns (bytes32) {
        return blockhash(1); // fails in Remix JS VM
    }
}
```

And found [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/72999) on Ethereum StackExchange that links to a deleted issue.

So if you need your contract to work in the Remix JS VM, I'd advise you to change the contract logic, so that it doesn't use the failing `blockhash()` function.

Comment: I don't think it's the blockhash issue because when I comment out just the line flipper.flip(side); above, the warning goes, even though there is a blockhash there as well. 

It might be that Remix just freaks out when it sees a ref to another contract so it over-cautions by throwing this warning just in case the other contract does have some weird stuff

Comment: @Vlad You also have the `blockhash()` used in the `doFlip()` function. So only commenting out the `flipper.flip(side);` line will still result in the revert, because there's still one more uncommented `blockhash()`.

Comment: in any event, the warning goes from remix if you do that